# Table join in hive fails

Tags: hive

I have following data for the 2 tables in hive

table1 contains

```
locn  zone

NY   AMERICA/CHICAGO
KC   AMERICA/DENVER
LA   AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

table 2 contains

```
stdtime              locn
2015-03-04 15:00:00  NY
2015-03-04 16:00:00  KC
```

This is my join query

```
select s.zone,t.stdtime,to_utc_timestamp(t.stdtime,s.zone) as newtime from table1 s inner join table2 t on s.locn=t.locn;
```

When I run this query on hortonworks cluster getting error

Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1430758596575_17289_7_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1430758596575_17289_7_01_000001, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"locn":"KC","zone":"America/Denver"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this

```
select s.zone,t.stdtime,to_utc_timestamp(t.stdtime,s.zone) as newtime from table1 s join table2 t on s.locn=t.locn;
```

In hive syntax is JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Comment: can you check the to_utc_timestamp(t.stdtime,s.zone) function? just remove this function and run once. just to be sure where we are getting the error.

Comment: With out this function it works. But when I include this function to_utc_timestamp(t.stdtime,s.zone) it fails.

Comment: that means the problem is with the function not with join. You are not passing proper parameter fpr the timezone field. look at the function again.

Comment: timestamp
 

to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)
 

Assumes given timestamp is in given timezone and converts to UTC (as of Hive 0.8.0). For example, to_utc_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00','PST') returns 1970-01-01 08:00:00.